# Color a call append(line)

Tags: highlight, color

I have cowfortune showing up at startup and I want to color it. How do I color the `call append()` line? I saw some things with signs but I didn't really get it to work.

```
enew
setlocal
    \ bufhidden=wipe
    " and some more options here...
for line in split(system('cowfortune -p'), '\n')
    " this is the line that I want to color!      
    call append('$', '        ' . l:line)
endfor
setlocal nomodifiable nomodified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go with it is to use the vim syntax highlighting mechanisms to do that. The first thing to do is to add `set filetype=cowfortune` to your function:

```
function Cow()
    enew
    set filetype=cowfortune
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe
    for line in split(system('ls -l'), '\n')
        call append('$', '        ' . l:line)
    endfor
    setlocal nomodifiable nomodified
endfunction
```

This way the buffer you are creating with your message has a defined filetype `cowfortune`. Now you can create the file `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/cowfortune.vim` which will contain the syntax instructions to be used in this buffer.

A very basic version of this file could be something like this:

```
" Guard to avoid loading the syntax file several times
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif
let b:current_syntax = "potion"

" Match all the existing text
syntax match cowText ".*"
" And highlight it as an error
highlight link cowText Error
```

What it does is create a syntax group named `cowText` and say that everything in the file should be attributed to this group (`.*`), see [`:h :syn-match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-match).

Then it creates a link to say that the group `cowText` should be shown like the group `Error` (see [`:h :hi-link`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahi-link))

With this code everything in your buffer will be highlighted in red (or however your colorscheme renders `Error`). Now these are some building block, you will need to change the match to apply your new group only to the message you want (I don't remember what `cowfortune` looks like but I think the message is displayed between `|` chars so maybe something like `|\zs.*\ze|`) and maybe you'll also want to create your own highlighting group.

To learn how to do all of that the help [`:h syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#syntax) is a very good place to start and learnvimscriptthehard way has [some very good material too](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html).

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks! I am very new to actually doing my own setup with vim, so all the :h suggestions were very useful. I set up different regions for the filetype with syn-region in the end to have different colored banners on Start.